# Am i being very inefficient ? mysqli call in loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, inner-join

I have a database with 2 tables, I have a primary key(item_id) and a foreign key(color_id) in the items table. I list the items out with the color as the title as below,

**Item details**

//item_id

//color_id

//Details

**Colors**

//Color_id

//color_suffix

//Color_details

I list these items out like 
Color Suffix(RE)
item details
item details
item details etc etc...

Color Suffix(RT)
Item details
item details

To do this i loop through the colors table and make an sql call each time it loops

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM COLORS";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while($data= fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<h2>{$data['color_suffix']}</h2>";
    $query2 = "SELECT ... FROM items WHERE color_id = {$data['color_id']}";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    while($item = fetch_array($result2)) {
        //List all items
    }
}
```

This is only kind of sudo code im just wondering if there is a more efficient way.
I've been reading up on SQL inner join, Would this be the method i should use ?

I've also read up on prepared statements, But ill be honest i do not really understand the syntax on either.

Should i be doing it like this ? or is it extremely inefficient ? Bear in mind there will be around 30 different colors then about 10 - 50 items each so that a lot of SQL calls.

Could someone provide some very basic sudo code to help me understand how i would achieve this ?

Thank you in advance
Ryan

Comment: 1+1n SQL requests will almost certainly be slower than 1 SQL request, especially as the value of n increases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use joins. Then add a little logic for your groupings.

```
 $query = "SELECT ... FROM COLORS, ITEMS WHERE items.color_id = colors.color_id order by colors.color_id";
 $stmnt = $db->prepare($query);
 $stmnt->bind_results($color_id, $color_suffix, ...);
 $stmnt->execute();
 $cur_col_id = '';
 while($stmnt->fetch())
 {
   if($color_id !== $cur_col_id)
   {
     echo '<h2>' . $color_suffix . '</h2>';
     $cur_col_id = $color_id;
   }
   //print the items here, no second loop.
 }
```

Keep in mind the ... shouldn't just be a *, it should be a list of actual fields you will be using.  The order has to match that in the bind_results call.  You should also add error checking and handling.

Comment: Thankyou, That makes alot of sense. Really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a simple inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM colors, items WHERE colors.color_id = items.color_id
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Could you quickly just sudo out how i would loop through that ?

I didnt realise it was that simple ?

Thankyou

Comment: The output is the same way you do it, its just that now you are reduced to a single loop.

Comment: The query i have just done works perfectly, Although im having trouble to display the same way i was, Ive managed to get it to output 
**color suffix**
//Item number
**(same as last color suffix)**
//Item number
etc etc

What i want is to have 
**Color Suffix**
//Item number
//Item number
//Item Number
**Next Color Suffix**
//Item number
//Item Number

The loop i used was 
    'while($data = fetch_array($result)) {
         echo "<h2>{$data['suffix']</h2>";
         echo "$data['item_number'];

}

I dont understand how id do it without a loop in a loop ?

Comment: The new result you fetch is containing both the columns of items and colors. Try running "print_r($data);" to see whats in it.